# How to automate the code to synchronization postgis live layer on pyqgis?

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins

I possess a dataset stored on a PostGIS server and aim to establish a fundamental synchronization mechanism through code. Although I've implemented the provided code for this purpose, when utilizing the QgsOfflineEditing plugin, it generates a GeoPackage database lacking information about the layers. Could someone please review the code to identify the reason for its malfunction on my end?

```
offline_editing = QgsOfflineEditing()
offline_data_path = QgsApplication.qgisSettingsDirPath()

file = os.path.join(offline_data_path, "offline.gpkg")
offline_editing.convertToOfflineProject(offline_data_path, "offline.gpkg", layers, containerType=QgsOfflineEditing.GPKG)
```

After that i will call the syncronize method on another event.

```
offline_editing.synchronize()
```

Comment: If you look here:  https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.0/core/other/QgsOfflineEditing.html#qgis.core.QgsOfflineEditing.convertToOfflineProject  , you will see the parameters required.  I think your "file" needs to go into the "offline_data_path" parameter and you will need some layer names in a list for the ""layers" parameter.

Comment: The offline data path is the qgis setting default path and also i have given the layers name list on the parameter as 
'layers = [lyr.name() for lyr in QgsProject.instance().mapLayers().values()]'